# React - Route return to desired page after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I created a very simple Login page that works, but how do I implement a way to return to the selected page after Login?
I think maybe is something related to `from` property passed in `Navigate`, but how can I get the page that the user selected and go to?

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
  <Route exact path='/Login' element={<Login />} />
  <Route
    path='/Apontar/:data_sel'
    element={<RequireAuth><Apontar /></RequireAuth>}
  />
  ...
```

```
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const { status, setStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
  let location = useLocation();

  if (status == null) {
    return <Navigate to="/Login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use useNavigate hook to achieve this action

```
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
const navigate=useNavigate();
if(status==null){
navigate('/login');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Navigate to="/Login" state={{ from: location }} replace />` passes the current route being accessed `location` object in route state. The `Login` component just accesses this passed state and issues a redirect back.

Example:

```javascript
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Login = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  const loginHandler = async () => {
    try {
      await /* authentication service /*
      const { from } = state || {};
      navigate(
        from.pathname || "/", // <-- target page or home
        { replace: true }     // <-- redirect
      );
    } catch(error) {
      ...
    }
  };

  ...
};
```